# Permission denied when piping to a file

Tags: bash, pipe, permission-denied

I'm trying to pipe the output of a "git pull" command to both a file and stdout using the following script:

```
STD_OUT=`mktemp`
git pull | $STD_OUT
rm -f $STD_OUT
```

This results in:

```
./test.sh: line 2: /tmp/tmp.BITQRbsMSI: Permission denied
error: git-pull died of signal 13
```

Why am I denied permission to the temp file I just created and what's the alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Piping to a file" is not a legal operation in `bash` (or any other shell).  The thing following a `|` has to be a command.  If you want to **redirect** the output from the `git` operation into the file, use the redirect operator `>`:

```
git pull > $STD_OUT
```

Comment: So is it possible to redirect to both a file and stdout?

Comment: Yes, there's a Unix command specifically for that, called `tee`.  The syntax there would be `git pull | tee $STD_OUT`.